# Play a random sound on a button click

Tags: android

I wonder if you could help. Im trying to play a random sound (from a set of 7 available sounds) when a user clicks on a button. So far I have:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int rndm = rand.nextInt(6) + 1; // I have 7 random sounds to play sequentially named 'my sound' + n.
String sndName = "mysound" + rndm;  // Assign a random # to the end of the sound file.   
mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sndName); // ERROR HERE: Expects an Int
mp1.start();
```

My hope was that one of my sound files (mysound1, mysound2, mysound3,...) would play randomly  but eclipse complains that the mp1 assignment is expecting an int. Any ideas?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
 int[] sounds={R.raw.mysound1, R.raw.mysound2, R.raw.mysound3,R.raw.mysound4,R.raw.mysound5,R.raw.mysound6,R.raw.mysound7};
```

Then

```
 Random r = new Random();
 int Low = 0;
 int High = 7;
 int rndm = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low; 
 mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),sounds[rndm]);
 mp1.start();
```

Comment: Thanks fpr everyones help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you need to get the resource id to pass in.  You'll need to use something like this.

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("mysound" + rndm, "raw", getApplicationInfo().packageName);
mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things. First I recommend you look at the line above where you create the string. If I remember correctly you may need to use a function such as to String to get the integer to be a string to concatenate on your string.

Next, I don't believe the r.raw is going to work like that.

My recommendation is if you have only 7 items, make an array holding the resources.

int [] resources = {R.raw.mysound1, R.raw.mysound2} etc

Then use the index from before to select the right R file.

So in the media create line, replace R.raw.sndName with resources[rndm]

Comment: Raghunandan beat me to it. Pick that one

Answer (score 0):

your program  using  variable error.     see below code:
    //  1. R.raw.sndName is Constant
    mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sndName); 
    // 2. android resource  must integer,  Starting from this idea